# MQTT async worker in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, celery, mqtt

In my Django application, I need to connect to a MQTT broker from several locations.

It will be great if I can create some kind of MQTT worker, which will run in the background/different thread and I can use this worker to publish/subscribe for messages and I don't have to create a separate MQTT connection for each function.

Example:

- Create MQTT worker with connection details. On startup, this connection is started and handled, restarted if connection lost, etc... (maybe use Celery for this?)
- Create functions which is available inside my Django projects for publish and subscribe. Publish seems more straighforward, but I'm not sure about the subscribe part.

My current implementation:

```
@shared_task(
    bind=True,
    name="tasks.send_command",
)
def send_command(self, username):
    pedestals = User.objects.filter(username=username)
    client = MqttClient("scheduled")
    client.connect()
    ...

@shared_task(
    bind=True,
    name="tasks.toggle_switch",
)
def toggle_switch(self, switch):
    from django.core.cache import cache
    client = MqttClient("toggle-switch")
    client.connect()
    ...
```

As you can see, I need to create the client in every task. Also I'm using it multiple times in Django as well, not just as a Celery task.
How can I create a worker for this. So like:

```
@shared_task(
    bind=True,
    name="tasks.toggle_switch",
)
def toggle_switch(self, switch):
    from django.core.cache import cache
    from mqtt.worker import mqtt_worker
    mqtt_worker.publish()
    ...
```

That way I could simplify my codebase and I would not have to wait for the client to connect every time the task runs.

I have found [mqttasgi](https://github.com/sivulich/mqttasgi) but I don't know if it will fit my needs.

Comment: What is the actual question here? You have stated a list of requirements, but not shown what you've tried and how it didn't work.

Comment: The question is how you would design a system with the requirements I stated. Anyway I will add some simple examples of why my current implementation does not seem right for me.

Comment: Added some examples from my current implementation